# The difference in dates (in months) are coming to be negative, 'some' dates such as Sep-74 are changed as '2074-09-01'?

Tags: python-3.x

So I am trying to find the number of months since the first loan applied.

1.pd.to_datetime('2017-12-01')-(loan_data['earliest_cr_line_date'])

2.round(pd.to_numeric((pd.to_datetime('2017-12-01')-loan_data['earliest_cr_line_date'])/np.timedelta64(1, 'M')))

But 'some' of the months are coming to be negative eg: Sep-1972 is changed as '2072-09-01'.

How to rectify this problem. Again I'll say there are some dates which are changed into this format ?

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use the `format` argument for those dates.

```
pd.to_datetime('Sep-1972', format="%m-/%Y")-(loan_data['earliest_cr_line_date'])
```

Comment: There are around 1400 rows where the problem exists.

Comment: Please, edit your question and provide a further description of your problem (learn how to format code). This has two advantages: 1) others can understand perfectly your problem; 2) by explaining what's going on, one can realize what the issue is